# When does a homeomorphism $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ preserve Borel sets with Lebesgue measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be an order preserving homeomorphism and let $m$ denote Lebesgue measure. I wish to show that given a Borel set $A\subset[0,1]$, $m(A)=0$ if and only if $m(h(A))=0$.

Now I know that this is not true in general. Let $C(x)$ be the Cantor function ("devil's staircase"). Then $f(x)=(1/2)(x+C(x))$ is a counter example. But suppose I know more...

Suppose that there exists a subset $D$ that is dense in $[0,1]$ such that for any $x\in D$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a subset $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ with $x\in[a,b]$ and $b-a<\epsilon$ such that
$$h(b)-h(a)=b-a.$$

**Question 1**: Is this enough to conclude that given a Borel set $A\subset[0,1]$, $m(A)=0$ if and only if $m(h(A))=0$? If not, what more is needed? (I think the answer is no, and that $h$ and $h^{-1}$ must be shown to be absolutely continuous, but perhaps there is an equivalent property that is easier to check.)

**Question 2**: Is this enough to conclude that $h'(x)=1$ for all $x\in D$? (I know that $h'(x)$ exists $m$-almost everywhere by Lebesgue's theorem for the differentiability of monotone functions.)

Any help at all is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The Cantor function is not a homeomorphism.

Comment: Haha, of course. Let $C(x)$ be the Cantor function. Then I think the homeomorphism I was actually thinking of was the function $f(x)=x+C(X):[0,1]\to[0,2]$. This maps the Cantor set (with measure zero) to a set with measure 1.